# Javascript setting opacity in function

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function fade(obj, time) {
    if(this) { //prevents the function from being called too many times at once
        addCallData(this);
    }
    if(!obj || !time) {
        alert("Object/time parameters are required.\n");
        return false;
    } else {
        if(!func_data[this]["fade"]) { /*if fade is not defined for [this], then define it*/
            func_data[this]["fade"] = ((obj.style.opacity)?1:(obj.style.filter));
        } else {
            if(func_data[this]["fade"] <= 0) { /*if object opacity has declined completely, then hide/remove the element to indicate that the object has faded*/
                obj.style.display="none";
                return false;
            }
            func_data[this]["fade"]=((func_data[this]["fade"])--); /*gradually reduce fade*/
            ((obj.style.filter)?((obj.style.filter)=func_data[this]["fade"]): 
           (obj.style.filter("alpha(opacity="+(func_data[this]["fade"])+"")));  /*ultimately, set opacity to x-0.1 or x-1*/
            setTimeout(function(){fade(obj, time);}, time); /*loop until false occurs*/
        }
    }    
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working.  I can set `func_data[this]["fade"]` to 0.50 and the HTML element will lose 50% of its opacity, but if I set the value of that property to opacity, the function will stop there and won't reach the timeout stage.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove it doesn't work.

Comment: i`if(this)` is completely useless. `this` is always coerced into object which is always truthy.

Comment: @pimvdb could you offer a clarification?

Comment: `if(this)` will always pass because `this` is always something. So you could eliminate `if(this) {` and `}`.

Comment: Then how should I refer to the function/object that has just been called without using [if(this){}] ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
function setOpacity(value) {
    testObj.style.opacity = value/10;
    testObj.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*10 + ')';
}
```

From reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/opacity.html

Comment: This doesn't work either (y is in global scope):     

    function fade(obj, time) {
      if(y<=0) { return false;}  
      y=((y)-0.1);
      obj.style.opacity=y;
      setTimeout(function(obj, time){fade(obj, time);}, 50);
    }